# scrolling view in android

Tags: android, layout

i have a code that run perfectly but in landscape mode the background images  are scrolling. i dont want scroll background image..
here is my code..

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"

    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
       />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:alpha="0.5"

        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sign"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Explore"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:alpha="0.5"

        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/signupp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
      />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the above code not run perfectly in labdscape mode..
i have created layout-land resource folder also.

Comment: As you are wrapping your `View` with `Scrollview`, everyting inside `Scrollview will be scrolled`. To not scroll your `view` put it out `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

You should put another LinearLayout with `layout_height` / `layout_width` with `fill_parent` around the `ScrollView` and set there the Background with `android:background="@drawable/bg"`